# WordPress add_action('wp_head'... not working

Tags: html, wordpress, pagespeed, preload

I'm trying to preload an image by adding a `<link rel="preload"...` to the site head, with the following code:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    add_action('wp_head', function(){ ?>
        <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/blog-bg-1536x907.jpeg" type="image/webp">
    <?php });
}
```

I've added this using the Code Snippets plugin. The snippet's active (on the front-end only) but it's not working. There's no errors in the debug log, I've tried changing the priority and even tried commenting out the `is_front_page()` conditional but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever I have problems with hooks, I try to make them as simple as possible. Can you try this one? Note, this will cause the site to stop working on the front end, so if you are testing this on a live site, have a tab open to the backend in order to undo this after testing. https://3v4l.org/4dA08

Comment: Don't put add_action inside a conditional.  Instead, put your conditional inside the callback function.  I realize you say you've tried this without the conditional, but this is more of a general rule you should always follow wjen using hooks and filters to avoid situations where the value of the conditional changes before and after the hook fires.

Comment: Do not use your current hook. There is a special filter hook `apply_filters( ‘wp_preload_resources’, array $preload_resources )` - see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_preload_resources/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_preload_resources/